# Этимология слова "конечно"

Tags: лексика

Слово "конечно" - это старославянизм, исконно русское или заимствованное?

Answer (score 4):

Конечно  ― **собственно русское слово**, суф. производное от "конец" , а "конец" ― общеславянское слово, суф. производное от общеславянского "кон" (граница).
Но все эти слова (конечно, конец, кон) относятся **к исконно русским словам**.

**Для справок (информация из Интернета)**

В словарном составе русского языка можно выделить два основных пласта слов: исконно русскую лексику и лексику заимствованную. Под исконно русской лексикой понимаются те слова, которые образовались непосредственно в русском языке в разные периоды его развития.

Есть несколько групп исконно русских слов). 1. Общеславянские слова, которые вошли в русский язык из славянского языка-основы. 2. Восточнославянские (или древнерусские) слова, которые возникли в русском языке примерно в XI—XIV вв. 3. Собственно русские слова, появившиеся начиная с XIV в. после разделения восточнославянского языка на украинский, белорусский и русский. Сюда относятся все слова, кроме заимствованных.

Особую группу заимствованных слов составляют старославянизмы. Так принято называть слова, пришедшие из старославянского языка, древнейшего языка славян. В IX в. этот язык был письменным языком в Болгарии, Македонии, Сербии, а после принятия христианства стал распространяться и на Руси в качестве письменного, книжного языка.